app icon Ws on Qt6.6 and Wayland in a flatpak on kde neon
i’m a kde guy (cuz I like Qt) and kde neon has kde6 on it that does wayland by default (yay:)
so I was testing my flatpak who’s runtime is kde/Qt 6.6
For one thing the windows seem to blaze open a lot faster than on kubuntu with x11. And I don’t see color artifacts I see on x11 (kubuntu) - I suspect it may be my kubuntu monitor has a loose hdmi cable sigh. But maybe it’s wayland vs x11? Not sure.
But I noticed all of my windows and dialogs have a W (top left) icon. At first I was goin “whaaat is that frickin yellow W ???” then I was like “oooh [W]ayland”…
Is there somethin I can do to fix my app icon? Or is that a “wayland/qt still need work” kinda thing? Anybody else using Qt besides me?

ok.  I got it.  Looks like there are SEVERAL things to make your app work properly with wayland sigh.
And it looks like it's more of a kde thing than qt thing.
https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Wayland_Porting_Notes#Application_Icon
Application Icon
On Wayland setWindowIcon() no longer works. This also means that currently is not possible to set a per-window icon (because the xdg-shell standard doesn't allow it). It is still possible to set the main application icon that will be shown in task managers and window decorations:
The name of the application icon will be fetched from the .desktop file of the application.
The name of the .desktop file must adhere to the reverse domain standard (e.g. org.kde.app.desktop).
Most of the KDE applications are already working fine because KAboutData takes care of all the necessary steps. If for some reason your application is not using KAboutData, you need to manually call QGuiApplication::setDesktopFileName().
